# Sending/Receiving strings & arrays between D' Shared Library, and Pascal (Lazarus) Host

Tags: arrays, string, d, pascal, calling-convention

I've made a shared library, which takes array of string, or just a string, as function parameters. I'm using the built-in "string" type, which comes in the D Language. I've tested the library in another D application, the library works. For GUI, I use Lazarus, and the problem is that I can't get Pascal's strings to be identified by the Library.

I'm using the AnsiString type in Pascal, and I believe that the default encoding in D is also ANSI. When an array of string has been sent to D, it gets completely messed up. In Pascal, I set its' length to 1, but using the debugger, I find that in the library, it becomes "3086778472". But that isn't t all, when this code is executed in the library:

```
line=<recieved-array-of-string's-name>[0];
```

It causes an 'External: SIGSEGV'. I've no idea what that error means.

My question here is: How do I convert a D string to a Pascal one, and then back again, and the same with arrays?

EDIT: I've tried Eugen Rieck's solution, it doesn't work. I think the problem isn't that; I've created another library, in D, with a function, that just returns a number (data type=ubyte), but that also doesn't work.

EDIY2: Further tracked the issue, I've found that library isn't receiving the parameters correctly.

Comment: Be careful not only with strings, but also with dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: Looks like your calling conventions don't match.

Answer (score 2):

D strings *are* Pascal strings.

A slice, or dynamic array, in D is simply a pointer (`arr.ptr`) and a length (`arr.length`). `string`, which is an alias of `immutable(char)[]` is no exception.

If you need to convert a D string to some `PascalString` struct, an easy and efficient way is to copy the pointer and length from the D string into the `PascalString` struct. To convert from a `PascalString` to a D string, slice the pointer: `pascalstring.pointer[0..pascalstring.length]`.

Two things to note, however:

- Since D strings are `immutable`, the `PascalString` pointer must be `const char*`. If it's not, you will need to create a mutable copy of the string (the easiest way is with `dup`).
- If you're allocating the strings with D's GC-managed memory, you need to be sure that D's GC can find the string, otherwise you risk the GC collecting the string while it's being used (D doesn't scan the memory that C libraries use).

Comment: Could you please add some example code, I can't understand without some code.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to pass strings around (while by far the technically worst) is the old C-Style 0-terminated version. This works "good enough" for human-readable strings.

On the D side: `toStringz()` and `fromStringz()` convert between a D string and a C string

On the FP side: The `PChar` family of fucntions provides support for C strings.

Comment: Is the strings are in an array, do I have to convert them one by one using toStringz or is there a function already?

Comment: And in which modules are those functions? EDIT: found them in std.string.

Comment: @Nafees The functions - as you said - are in std.string, I am not aware of an array function - but this should be quite trivial to write via `opApply()` on a `range` derived from the array.

Comment: Those function are for immutable char*, but my whole code will have to be rewritten for that, is there a way to get the mutable ones?

Comment: Actually, a pointer to char and a separate length parameter would be better match for pascal strings, since pascal strings can contain character 0.  ansistrings are typecastable to C char*, and always contain a \0 at the end, but might also have them inside.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort - nice to hear from you! You have put your finger right on what I ment with "the technically worst" but "good enough for human-readable strings". Since this is about a UI I was quite confident, that null characters in the String would not be an issue.